# add command to /etc/init.d/rc.local file that's missing

Tags: fedora, init-script

Want to add the command

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf H_DRIVE /media/windows7share
```

to `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file, to run the command every time when system starts up but I don't have such a file (`rc.local`) in that folder. What is the workaround?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: filesystems to be mounted at boot are in /etc/fstab, even cifs mounts can be added, with security credentials stored in another file. Search for fstab cifs credentials

Comment: @Piskvor it might be. Often /etc/rc.local is a symlink to ``/etc/init.d/rc.local``.

Comment: Are you sure you are using ``sysinit``? If your system is using ``upstart`` or ``systemd`` or something similar, there might not be an ``rc.local``. (Unless the system was configured for that).

Answer (score 6):

The workaround is to mount the entry in /etc/fstab.  It should look something like this:

```
H_DRIVE    /media/windows7share   vboxsf    defaults        0 0
```

There's no reason for an RC script (which runs as root) to run 'sudo' to mount the volume.  In this case, you don't even need to use an rc script at all.

Answer (score 2):

Where the "local" scripts file lies is distro-dependent. Here it is the set of files under `/etc/local.d/`, some systems will have `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, others, as Piskvor mentions, may have `/etc/rc.local`.

According to fedorafaq.org, [this file is `/etc/rc.local`](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#startonboot). If there's no such file, create it. Depending on how Fedora does it, the file may need the executable bit (`chmod +x`).

Comment: Fedorafaq is wrong about the location.  It should be `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.  Fedora 15 creates a symlink from /etc/rc.local to /etc/rc.d/rc.local, I believe, but Fedora 16 does not, so creating it will do nothing.  It must be executable.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using the automounter to mount that partition only if needed.
Look at **autofs** and **/etc/auto.mnt** for details.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Fedora 20. Mounting in fstab fails for me. There is a [documented bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=967321) that mounting vboxsf in fstab fails at boot time. I moved the mount to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` which made with the joyousness.

Answer (score 0):

In **Fedora 20** (and 21), you should create the file under */etc/rc.d/*:

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Inside, add the *sh shebang*, your command (without *"sudo"*) and *exit*:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t vboxsf <SHARE_FOLDER> /home/<username>/<HOST>
exit 0
```

And ensure the file is executable:

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Comment: and make sure it's got the +x mode bit set.